# Error while wrappin PLSQL procedure please help me

Tags: oracle, plsql, syntax-error, word-wrap

I am facing an error while wrapping PLSQL procedure. below is my code and error

**Actual Function:**

```
create or replace function column_job_salary_restriction(
    v_schema        in varchar2,
    v_object        in varchar2
    ) return varchar2
         is
    v_sql varchar2(100);
        begin
    if lower( sys_context( 'userenv', 'session_user') ) = 'user2' then
            v_sql := '0 = 1';
        end if;
            return v_sql;
end;
```

/

**WRAPPING CODE:**

```
DECLARE
       INPUT DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2S;
       OUTPUT DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2S;
       BEGIN
       INPUT(1) := 'create or replace function column_job_salary_restriction( v_schema in varchar2, v_object in varchar2) return varchar2 is';
       INPUT(2) := 'v_sql varchar2(100) := null;';  
   INPUT(3) := 'begin';
   INPUT(4) := 'if lower(sys_context("userenv","session_user")) = "user2" then';
       INPUT(5) := 'v_sql := '0 = 1';';
   INPUT(6) := 'end if;';   
       INPUT(7) := 'return v_sql';
       INPUT(8) 'end;';
       SYS.DBMS_DDL.CREATE_WRAPPED(DDL => INPUT,
                                                                        LB  => 1,
                                                                        UB  => INPUT.COUNT);
       END;
```

### /

**ERROR:**

```
ERROR at line 9:
ORA-06550: line 9, column 35:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "0" when expecting one of the following:
* & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
<an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset
```

---

After executing `EXEC column_job_salary_restriction`

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
'COLUMN_JOB_SALARY_RESTRICTION'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Please help me I am new to PLSQL.

Comment: Why are you trying to wrap a function?

Answer (score 2):

About PLS-00103:

```
INPUT(5) := 'v_sql := '0 = 1';';
```

Should be:

```
INPUT(5) := 'v_sql := ''0 = 1'';';
```

The double-quote is one way to escape a quote inside a string.

About PLS-00306:

```
declare
  v_ret varchar2(100);
begin
  v_ret := column_job_salary_restriction('foo', 'bar');
end;
/
```

It is a function so you have to bind the return value to a variable and you also have to give the values to input parameters.

Comment: ERROR:
ORA-24344: success with compilation error
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DDL", line 754
ORA-06512: at line 13



Warning: PL/SQL compilation errors.